# how to send a clickable link to gmail message body and google plus message while sharing in iOS

Tags: html, ios, iphone, email, uiactivityviewcontroller

I want to send a clickable link to gmail message body and google plus message  while sharing in iOS.I have tried many ways with HTML.But end up with issue

Now I m using below string to mail message body:

[image]

I m getting the output as shown in picture but link in mail is not clickable.

I am setting the message body as:

```
[self.globalMailComposer setMessageBody:message isHTML:YES];
```

Can any please let me know where am I going wrong

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace your link with href

```
<a href='your link should be here'>Open This</a>
```

For example :

```
NSString *link = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.google.com"];
[controller setMessageBody:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<a href=%@>%@</a>",link,@"Google"] isHTML:YES];
```

Comment: @Sujania when you send the mail to other then they can click on it, from the mail composer. I don't think you can click

Comment: recipient can open the link from the mail. @Sujania try to send it

Comment: its working perfectly after checking the mail.. Actually I have used in phonegap customplugin..thanks a lot you have saved my time :)